# Why is the token set ratio so low using fuzzywuzzy?

Tags: python, token, fuzzywuzzy, rapidfuzz

I am using fuzzywuzzy and rapidfuzz to find names mentioned in comments. I read through the documentation of the "token_set_ratio" function but I still don't understand the following:

```
# I preprocessed the comments to remove stop words and commonly mentioned other words

fuzz.token_set_ratio("reporting michael anders sven straumann guy called jonatjan smith partners","jonathan smith")

# returns 52.6
```

Jonathan Smith has only one spelling mistake, why is the ratio so low?

Moreover, would there be an option to overcome the problem so that Jonathan receives a higher score?

thanks for your help,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

`Fuzz.token_set_ratio` is not really the right ratio for your problem, since it sorts the words, while you would like to keep the pairing of first and second name. You could use `fuzz.partial_ratio` to compare only the best matching substring of the longer string to the shorter string.

```py
fuzz.partial_ratio(
  "reporting michael anders sven straumann guy called jonatjan smith partners",
  "jonathan smith")
# returns 92.85714285714286
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. This actually solves the specific problem I mentioned here. However, this function will (for instance) return 100 for each michael mentioned and not only for michael anders.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you mean. Do you mean that it returns 100 when you search for "michael" instead of "jonathan smith"?

Comment: My actual problem is that I have a list of names, be it [jonathan smith, michael anders, michael stralund,...] and I am trying to find all the names that are mentioned in each comment. Now when I apply token_set_ratio the score for the missspelled jonathan is so low that I would need to exclude it. However, using partial_token_set leads to 100 for both michaels although only one is mentioned.

Comment: I updated the anser. Using fuzz.partial_ratio should work a lot better for your use case.